# Panda .loc or .iloc to select the columns from a dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have been trying to select a particular set of columns from a dataset for all the rows. I tried something like below.

```
train_features = train_df.loc[,[0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]]
```

I want to mention that all rows are inclusive but only need the numbered columns.
Is there any better way to approach this.

sample data:

```
age  job        marital   education    default   housing   loan   equities   contact     duration   campaign   pdays   previous   poutcome   emp.var.rate   cons.price.idx   cons.conf.idx   euribor3m     nr.employed   y
56   housemaid  married   basic.4y     1         1         1      1          0           261        1          999     0          2          1.1            93.994           -36.4           3.299552287   5191          1
37   services   married   high.school  1         0         1      1          0           226        1          999     0          2          1.1            93.994           -36.4           0.743751247   5191          1
56   services   married   high.school  1         1         0      1          0           307        1          999     0          2          1.1            93.994           -36.4           1.28265179    5191          1
```

I'm trying to neglect job, marital, education and y column in my dataset. y column is the target variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If need select by positions use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
train_features = train_df.iloc[:, [0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]]
print (train_features)
   age  default  housing  loan  equities  contact  duration  campaign  pdays  \
0   56        1        1     1         1        0       261         1    999   
1   37        1        0     1         1        0       226         1    999   
2   56        1        1     0         1        0       307         1    999   

   previous  poutcome  emp.var.rate  cons.price.idx  cons.conf.idx  euribor3m  \
0         0         2           1.1          93.994          -36.4   3.299552   
1         0         2           1.1          93.994          -36.4   0.743751   
2         0         2           1.1          93.994          -36.4   1.282652   

   nr.employed  
0         5191  
1         5191  
2         5191
```

Another solution is [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) unnecessary columns:

```
cols= ['job','marital','education','y']
train_features = train_df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (train_features)
   age  default  housing  loan  equities  contact  duration  campaign  pdays  \
0   56        1        1     1         1        0       261         1    999   
1   37        1        0     1         1        0       226         1    999   
2   56        1        1     0         1        0       307         1    999   

   previous  poutcome  emp.var.rate  cons.price.idx  cons.conf.idx  euribor3m  \
0         0         2           1.1          93.994          -36.4   3.299552   
1         0         2           1.1          93.994          -36.4   0.743751   
2         0         2           1.1          93.994          -36.4   1.282652   

   nr.employed  
0         5191  
1         5191  
2         5191
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael.. Thanks for the quick reply. But unfortunately I tried the above ways and I'm getting the below error.

     TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Couldn't able to figure out why this issue comes in. Can you provide any pointers?

Comment: Can you add some sample of data?

Answer (score 5):

You can access the column values via the the underlying numpy array

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 20)))
df
```

[image]

You can slice the underlying array

```
slc = [0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
df.values[:, slc]

array([[1, 3, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1, 6, 6, 0, 3, 9, 8, 5, 9, 9],
       [8, 0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 9],
       [1, 1, 9, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 8, 0, 5, 4, 9, 0],
       [6, 3, 1, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 9, 0, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 8],
       [3, 2, 3, 3, 9, 8, 3, 8, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 6, 4]])
```

Or you can reconstruct a new dataframe from this slice

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[:, slc], df.index, df.columns[slc])
```

[image]

This is **not** as clean and intuitive as

```
df.iloc[:, slc]
```

You could also use `slc` to slice the `df.columns` object and pass that to `df.loc`

```
df.loc[:, df.columns[slc]]
```

[image]